# Python: Using functions of parent package in child package

Tags: python

I have a python file in which I am importing 2 packages.

In `C.py`:

```
from A import a
from B import b
```

However, I want to use the use the functionality of package C in A and B.

In `B.py`:

```
from A import a
from C import c
```

In `A.py`:

```
from C import c
```

`C` is my main file. 
However, when I run `C.py` I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name c
```

I get that perhaps I am trying to import a file inside itself and it is probably causing the issue.
What is the solution for this?

Comment: If you have circular dependencies that seems like a design flaw more than a python flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While circular imports are not recommended and to me indicate that you need to rethink your design, you can get away with them by doing the import inside the function that needs to refer to C:

```
class A(object):
  def circular_func(self):
    from c import C
    C.needed_function()
```

I want to stress again that I do not recommend this approach. It will work, but you should be thinking about how to break this circle, not how to get away with it.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen one of my answers be accepted while having a negative rating. I'm amused.